# Rails 3 break users edit into categories

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2, edit

I have a Rails3 app (I'm new to rails) that allows users to sign up by filling name, email, password, password_conf.

Once signedup, I d like users to be able to edit more attributes through different forms, (Attributes such as an avatar image, address, etc..), in order to have an edit page which would not include too much information.

What is the best way to create different forms for the user to edit attributes separately, for example:

Edit General Info (name, email), Edit Password, Edit address, Edit picture

Was thinking of adding new routes

resources :users do
    member do
      get :general_info, :password, :address, :picture
    end
  end

Should I use nested attributes in order to keep a unique edit action in users controller, or add new actions?

Any advice for best practices would be extremely appreciated!
Thx

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it should be a step by step process, where first when the user signs up, it is shown the first from (eg. General Info), when he clicks on skip or submit, he is shown the next form and so on.

In this case, the best way to do this is, to have a separate action for each form. There will be one view file for each form. This will make your code more readable and easy to understand. This implies, that you need separate routes for each file, as you suggested.

But if you are using some JS Framwork(eg. AngularJS) to manage your interactions, you can also put all the forms in the single file with a single edit option.